# Running projects in google cloud console

Tags: python, console, cloud

I am new to google cloud console and I am trying to run a python script which is stored in a storage bucket. I was not able to find a documentation for this. Does anyone know?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to run the script from the cloud console?

In this case, you can just copy the file from GS to the console instance with `gsutil` and then run it:

```
gsutil cp gs://path_to_file/filename.py . && python filename.py
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I wanted to, in the meantine I discovered that I can connect to the vm using ssh. The problem now is that I have some requirements for my project - I am running a tensorflow project and I have dependencies like pandas and keras. Do you have any idea if I should put them when creating the tpu instance or is there another option? :)

Comment: If you're launching the instance manually and setting up the environment yourself, you can just install your requirements as you would on any machine : e.g. one by one, or with a requirements.txt file, or with a setup.py file... etc. 

If you're looking to submit a training job to the AI Platform service for example, you'll need to package your code accordingly. I believe the documentation is quite good if that's what you're trying to do.